# Matching Rules Set with input data set in Java

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching

I'm working on a problem where I have two Input sets

**Input1 :**

**Multiple Set of rules (Sample):**

**RuleSet1:**

```
1. I am $name
2. I am $age years old
3. $bookname is my favorite book
   ....
```

**RuleSet2:**

```
1. I love $sportname
2. $color is my favorite color
   ....
```

**RuleSet3:**

```
1. $fruit is my favorite fruit
2. I am a $diet
3. I speak $language
4. I am from $countryname
   ....
```

Here $name,$age,$bookname... are placeholders. There could be multiple such rule sets. There is no limit.

**Input2 :**

Multiple Set of Input Strings.

**Set 1:**

```
1. I am 26 years old
2. I am James
   .....
```

**Set 2:**

```
1. I am John
2. ToKillAMockinBird is my favorite book
   .......
```

**Set 3:**

```
1. TuesdaysWithMorrie is my favorite book
2. I am Bill
3. I am 26 years old
   ......
```

**Set 4:**

```
1. I am Jack
2. I am 27 years old
3. WarAndPeace is my favorite book
   ......
```

**Set 5:**

```
1. I am a vegan
2. I speak English
   ......
```

**Set 6:**

```
1. Purple is my favorite color
2. I love football
   ......
```

**Problem Statement :**

For each Set of Strings in Input 2, I need to match with Input 1 and say if these strings appeared in the same order or not.

**Output :**

```
Set1 --> false
Set2 --> true
Set3 --> false
Set4 --> true
Set5 --> true
Set6 --> false
```

I tried brute force by iterating each string in each input set and checking if it exists or not, if so, giving them a number, finally checking if these numbers are in ascending order or not. But, it's not efficient. The input Set1, set2 could be huge data sets. Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: The brute force can be optimized to break the iteration as soon as the order is not maintained for a particular input set, instead of matching and assigning numbers to all.

Comment: You can make a modified trie datastructure for all ruleset having order as variable. Now you can search inputs in that trie and match the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thought: concatenate the lines in the rule sets and input sets into one line with some special delimiter (or alternately a surrounding pattern)

so rule set #1 can look like this
`I am $name ### I am $age years old ### $bookname is my favorite book`
or like this
`[I am $name] [I am $age years old] [$bookname is my favorite book]`

then you can do the same for the input sets and compare. seems to me like replacing the placeholders with regex `\w+` may be sufficient